# How to run a code for all functions in the same class?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is how my code looks like:

```
public function __construct() {
    global $wpdb;
}

private function get_pagination() {
    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yc_customers WHERE $this->get_where" );
}
```

When I run it, I'll get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_var() on a non-object

When I copy `global $wpdb;` to my `get_pagination()` function, then I don't get any errors. I don't want to copy it in all my functions though. Why am I getting this error, even when I have the `global $wpdb` in the `__construct` function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use `global`, **and you don't want it**, then you can do something like:

```
private function get_pagination() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yc_customers WHERE $this->get_where" );
}
```

But you can simply pass the variable in the constructor, like:

```
public function __construct($wpdb) {
    $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
}

private function get_pagination() {
    $user_count = $this->wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yc_customers WHERE $this->get_where" );
}
```

Look for "dependency injection".